# Nodejs generate secure random characters not including given chars

Tags: node.js, random, cryptojs

I was reading about generating secure random generator in nodejs.
I tried this and works well to generate secure random characters.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var length = 22
var generated = crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length / 2))
                      .toString('hex').slice(0, length);
//it returned "14cf777d3ca307f5e78496"
```

How can I generate secure random characters not including given `pattern` in nodejs.
Ex: `['a', '2']`, it should return secure chars without given pattern `14cf777d3cr307f5e78496`

Comment: It tempts me to paste the "You have no power here" meme... Anyway, what are the requirements? That the output of `toString("hex")` contains none of the given chars? Good luck with that. You can replace them though, say, `generated = generated.replace(/a/g, "r");` The hex representation has only 16 valid characters, so you can safely use the remaining letters of the alphabet as replacements without losing any information.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make sure that the generated and parsed string should not contain any patterns given in your array?

Comment: @KamilSolecki yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) does not offer directly what you are looking for. 
Although, what you can do, is to keep recursively generating your crypto until none of the patterns are found inside.

For that, you can use the following:

```
async function generateRandomCrypto(length, patterns) {
    const generated = await crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length / 2)).toString('hex').slice(0, length);

    let isValid = true;
    for (pattern of patterns) {
        if (generated.indexOf(pattern) !== -1) {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isValid) {
        return await generateRandomCrypto(length, patterns);
    }

    return generated;  
}
```

Now, the function will keep generating until it finds one that does not include any of the strings provided in the `patterns` array.

If you are somehow worried about any kind of performance impact - there is no need to.

Assuming your patterns are not single letter strings, it is very unlikely that they will appear in the random sequence - thus, the generation might run only once.

And *even if*, I did a test for you - I ran this with a patterns array looking like that:

```
const patterns = ['a', 'b'];
```

And I had 4 - 8 function executions on average.

Comment: good approach. My pattern may contain numbers, capital, lower case letters. Say length is 32, and pattern `abcdefghijkl`. How can I validate performance impact?

Comment: The chance for `abcdefghijkl` to appear in the `random` generated sequence of 32 characters is incredibly low. You can run your function X times, while, for example, keeping a counter on how many times the function was executed. The 'extra' executions you will be able to calculate by doing `counter - X` - since then it would mean that the function ran more than once for each 'test execution'

Comment: Still, my guess is that if you ran this, say, 100000 times, you wouldn't likely have a single match with such a pattern.

Comment: This creates a very deep call stack, risking a stack overflow. Using promises likely worsens this. Try recursing with a loop instead.

(Correct me if I'm wrong about the function-call stack)